# How to programmatically create xml with VTD-XML?

Tags: java, xml, vtd-xml

I want to create an xml with this shape where I insert the inner elements `/a/b` in a loop and also set the attributes on element `b`.

```
<ROOT>
  <a>
    <b attr1="1" attr2="a"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b attr1="1" attr2="b"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b attr1="2" attr2="a"/>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b attr1="2" attr2="b"/>
  </a>
</ROOT>
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
  public static String createXML(Collection<Integer> numbers, Collection<String> words) {
    String charsetName = "UTF-16";
    byte[] root = "<ROOT></ROOT>".getBytes(charsetName);
    VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
    ap.selectXPath("/ROOT");
    XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();
    vg.setDoc(root);
    vg.parse(false);
    VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
    ap.bind(vn);
    xm.bind(vn);

    byte[] aTag = "<a></a>".getBytes(charsetName);
    byte[] bTag = "<b />".getBytes(charsetName);

    int i;

    String collect = numbers.stream().flatMap(number -> words.stream().map(word -> {
      try {
        xm.insertAfterHead(aTag);
        ap.selectXPath("a");
        xm.insertAfterHead(bTag);
        ap.selectXPath("b");
        xm.insertAttribute(String
          .format(" attr1=\"%d\" attr2=\"%s\"",
            number,
            word));
        return xm.outputAndReparse().toNormalizedString(0);
      } catch (ModifyException | NavException | ParseException | IOException | TranscodeException | XPathParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(""));

    return collect;
  }
```

I get a ModifyExcpetion because I call insertAfterHead twice.
How can I generate the desired xml shape? I do not fully understand how to put the offset to the right place yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may know what you are trying to accomplish. There are a few sugggestions

- selectXPath(a) merely compiles an xpath into internal format... It does not evaluate into a node set for you. To evaluate it, you need to call evalXPath().
- You want to insert as many  into under root node as possible as a single string concatenation. The actually string concatenation operation should occur as an independent part of your app logic. In VTD-XML, you think in terms of bits bytes, byte arrays and int/long arrays.

Below is my mod of your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException,IOException,
    UnsupportedEncodingException{
        String charsetName = "UTF-16";
        byte[] root = "<ROOT><a><b/></a><a><b/></a><a><b/></a><a><b/></a></ROOT>"
    .getBytes(charsetName); // that is template you want to start with
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        ap.selectXPath("/ROOT/a/b");
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier();
        vg.setDoc(root);
        vg.parse(false);
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        ap.bind(vn);
        xm.bind(vn);
        int i=0;
        int[] ia = new int[4];
        ia[0]=1;ia[1]=1;ia[2]=2;ia[3]=2;
        String[] sa = new String[4];
        sa[0]="a";sa[1]="b";sa[2]="a";sa[3]="b";
        int k=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.insertAttribute( String.format(" attr1=\"%d\" attr2=\"%s\"",
                    ia[k],
                    sa[k]));
            k++;
        }
        XMLByteOutputStream xbos = new XMLByteOutputStream(xm.getUpdatedDocumentSize());
        xm.output(xbos);
        System.out.println(new String(xbos.getXML(),"UTF-16"));
    }
```

Comment: This works as long as the doc has a fixed size. Can I use vtd-xml to add the elements `/a/b` based on the previously unknown size of ia and sa? Or should I just not use vtd-xml for this use case and create the whole document through string concatenation, that is stringbuffer the start root tag element, append the `/a/b` elements with the attributes in a loop and finalize the stringbuffer with the closing root tag element outside the loop.

Comment: it is a matter of preference... concatenating strings is in my view the most intuitive way to create the XML document... and you have total control of everything... and it is not hard at all...